# Pass dataTable rows into another dataTable in c#

Tags: c#

I have  datatable (dt) values fetched from database...(the fields are CID,CNAME)

I need to copy rows one by one from dataTable (dt) into another dataTable (dtrow) to pass it as parameter in a function.

Here's what I'm coding

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
{
    Datarow[] dr = dt.Select("CID= " + dt.Rows[i]["CID"]);
    dtrow.ImportRow(dr[0]);

    fn_pass(dtrow)

}

public void fn_pass(DataTable dt)
{
    //Do something
}
```

I checked that dataTable dtrow is getting rows but there is no content. Seems blank rows getting inserted.
How can I correct this code.

Comment: `public fn_pass(DataTable dt)` is missing a return type

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Im not adding much details of the code. Just the dataTable part as the same is not working.

Comment: Why not just pass the first datatable?

Comment: @CaiusJard can we pass the first dataTable row by row? Will the function parameter take it if passed as dt.Rows(i)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first question, but I can answer *will the function parameter take it if passed as Rows(i)* - no; Rows is a property that returns a DataRowCollection, so you cannot put `(` after it - it's not a method. The function is defined as accepting a datatable; you need to give it a datatable